# Angular 7 library - how to bundle dependencies without adding them to the main app

Tags: angular, angular7

I have an *Angular 7* application that I created with the `@angular/cli` and then I added a library to using `ng generate library`. It works fine in `dev` mode and such. There's no problems.

I'd like to keep the dependencies that are relevant to the library contained to it; And not clutter up the main application's `package.json`. So, naturally, I did `npm install --save [xyx]` to the library folder. That worked fine. Still runs great in `dev` mode.

But when I try to do `ng build --prod`, suddenly it can't find the dependencies that are part of the library. The reason why is obvious, of course; They're not being properly bundled in. I've investigated `npm`'s `bundleDependencies` feature to no avail, and I've looked at the `lib: { embedded: ... }` and `whitelistedNonPeerDependencies` option for `ng-package.json`, but I can't seem to make any of them do quite what I want.

This isn't a make or break requirement; If it's absolutely mandatory, I will just install the dependencies in the main application. But I'd very much like to avoid that. Perhaps it's an unreasonable goal, I am unsure.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I tried to do what you described locally and didn't have an issue. Here were the steps I took.

1. `npm install @angular/cli`
2. `node_modules/.bin/ng new installtest`
3. `cd installtest`
4. `node_modules/.bin/ng generate library libtest`
5. `cd projects/libtest`
6. `npm install --save numeral`
7. `npm install --save-dev @types/numeral`
8. added `ro.pipe.ts` to `projects/libtest/src`

   ```
   import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

   import * as numeral from 'numeral';

   @Pipe({name: 'decimalUnit'})
   export class RoPipe implements PipeTransform {
     constructor() {
       numeral.register('locale', 'ro', {
           delimiters: {
               thousands: '.',
               decimal: ','
           },
           abbreviations: {
               thousand: 'k',
               million: 'm',
               billion: 'b',
               trillion: 't'
           },
           ordinal: function (number) {
               return number === 1 ? 'er' : 'ème';
           },
           currency: {
               symbol: 'RON'
           }
       });

       numeral.locale('ro');
   }

     public transform(value: string, numDecimals: number) {
       const b = numeral(value);
       let x = '0,0.';
       for (let i = 0; i < numDecimals; i++) {
           x = x + '0';
       }

       return b.format(x);
     }
   }
   ```
9. update `projects/libtest/src/lib/libtest.module.ts`

   ```
   import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
   import { LibtestComponent } from './libtest.component';
   import { RoPipe } from './ro.pipe';

   @NgModule({
     declarations: [LibtestComponent, RoPipe],
     imports: [
     ],
     exports: [LibtestComponent, RoPipe]
   })
   export class LibtestModule { }
   ```
10. update `projects/libtest/src/public_api.ts`

    ```
    export * from './lib/libtest.service';
    export * from './lib/libtest.component';
    export * from './lib/libtest.module';
    export * from './lib/ro.pipe';
    ```
11. update `tsconfig.json`. add `"projects/libtest/node_modules/@types"` to `"typeRoots"` array
12. update `src/app/app.module.ts`

    ```
    import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
    import { LibtestModule } from 'projects/libtest/src/public_api';

    import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

    @NgModule({
      declarations: [
        AppComponent
      ],
      imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        LibtestModule
      ],
      providers: [],
      bootstrap: [AppComponent]
    })
    export class AppModule { }
    ```
13. update `src/app/app.component.html`

    ```
    <label>{{ '12345678' | decimalUnit:2 }}</label>
    <br>
    <label>{{ '12345678' | decimalUnit:0 }}</label>
    <br>
    <label>{{ '12345678' | decimalUnit:2 }}</label>
    <br>
    <label>{{ '12345678' | decimalUnit:2 }}</label>
    <br>
    <label>{{ '12345678' | decimalUnit:2 }}</label>
    ```

After this, I ran `npm run start` to verify that it works with the dev build. Next I ran `npm run start -- --prod` to verify that it works with the prod build. Both worked. The last thing I did was to run `npm run build` and `npm run build -- --prod` and loaded the website through IIS, both of which worked. I put the full repo project on [GitHub](https://github.com/PdUi/stack-overflow-answer-repos/tree/master/npm-install-test) for reference.

You don't really provide an [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). So it is hard to tell you why your particular project isn't working at the moment. If the above steps don't work for you, please provide more detail as to what you have tried exactly that is failing(or at least a minimal project that can reproduce the issue you are encountering).

Comment: It's true that I didn't provide a good MVCE, I apologize. I'll see if I can't create one shortly. Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: Per your assertion, this did, indeed, work as I want. I am having a difficult time figuring out what I have done differently, but the key step you take that I did not is putting extra content into the `typeRoots` array of the `tsconfig.json`.

I don't fully understand how this works just yet, but you have proven it can be done, you've given me enough to go on, and your example runs as desired, so I'll award the points. Thank you so much. I am sorry it took me so long to respond.

Comment: Looks like the community beat me to it. My apologies again. Hectic life and everything. Your example is great. I'll make a fork of your repo so you can delete it. I apologize once more.

Comment: Is there a way I can provide extra bounty? @peinearydevelopment

Comment: And if I may ask - why did you go directly into the `node_modules` folder to create the library, instead of just using `ng generate` at the root of the Angular project? Is there a reason for this? Or is that just how you've always done it?

Comment: The specific library I am trying to do this with is `ngx-scrollbar`, presently.

Comment: Thanks for your responses. 1. I always use node_modules/..., This is due to the fact that I don't install the cli globally. I like using the local copy for development as it is clear to me which version I'm using(it's the one in the package.config). 2. It is possible that this method won't work for you which is why I was looking for an MVCE. There are different module types in the js world. It is possible that it will only work for some of those types and not others(or due to some other factor). If you narrow it down more, feel free to open another more specific question on SO. All the best.

Comment: Your habit led me to the **final** part of the problem. I had to include `ngx-scrollbar` in the `paths` of the **root** `tsconfig`, and point it to the `packages/core/node_modules/ngx-scrollbar` file so it could be found. After this, things worked as expected! Thank you so much again! You are amazing!

Comment: I'll still try to make an MVCE to show you in the future. Basically, I'm meticulous and OCD - and I would **like** to keep packages contained only in the libraries they belong in. I realize the very nature of multi-repo libraries discourages this, but it is a development practice that works well for **me**, so it's one of those situations of trusting my instincts instead of the convention. However, it is not a stop-ship deal. I can function without it - but it's a nicety I really wanted to have if it were feasible.

Comment: @Ciel I like the idea of keeping deps contained, just never thought to try myself. I think you will want to add a step to your main `packages.json` though that will install the libraries divs when you run `npm install` in the main project directory. Also, if there are other issues you encounter with the build, I did write a blog post on [how to debug the build](https://blog.pinarydevelopment.com/visual-studio-code/debug-angular-build).

Comment: This method still seems to cause trouble with PWA with the service worker file; I'll post here if I figure out how to get around that.

Comment: Good news! I solved the PWA problem! I'll post more shortly.

Comment: This is a neat approach. Please share when you can!

Comment: Great explanation. I had imported lib Component instead of lib Module in the application. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know this is not possible.

To somewhat solve your "problem" you could create a completly new cli project. In the new project generate your library and other future libraries. The new project can be some showcase/docs for your libraries. This way all of your libraries will use the same version of dependencies but are not included into your main application.